# How to add list (numbers) in views so output shows numbers ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add numbers in the list

```
<% @name.each do |name| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= name.fname %></td>
    <td><%= name.lname %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I want to make it like 
1. John Doe
2. Jane Doe

but not sure which is the standard way to add

as when I added

```
<td><li></li></td>,
```

it is not showing the numbers but only

, I am sure I am missing something very small, but not sure what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @name.each_with_index do |name, index| %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= index+1 %></td>
    <td><%= name.fname %></td>
    <td><%= name.lname %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Buddy its not

```
<td><li></li></td>
```

rather its

```
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is an ordered list:

```
<ol>
  <% @name.each do |name| %>
    <li>
      <%= name.fname %> <%= name.lname %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```